# nav bar will not change colour. Corrected html and css markup. No effect

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have a navbar on my website.  But the font is orange and the hover...white.

I want the font white and the background purple.  I cannot seem to override the bootstrap.css even though my style.css is below the bootstrap.css.  I've even tried filling in every colour in .nav bar with #000000; to see what would happen and commenting out...**no effect!**

The only thing that changes is the margin.  Originally the issue was my html markup..but I've corrected it..however the issue still persists.  The font is orange but I have no idea how it's orange as I've looked through both the style.css and bootstrap.css.

Help would be greatly appreciated.  **Thank you**

index.html

```
<!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <!-- logo -->
    <ng-controller="demoCtrl">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li ng-class="{active: isState('home') }">
          <a ui-sref="home">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: isState('form') }">
          <a ui-sref="form">CANDIDATES</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: isState('clients') }">
          <a ui-sref="clients">CLIENTS</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: isState('aboutus') }">
          <a ui-sref="aboutus">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>

        <li ng-class="{active: isState('training') }">
          <a ui-sref="training">TRAINING</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <h3 class="text-muted">          </h3>
      <br>
  </div>
</header>
```

style.css

```
/* general settings */
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
body {
  background-color: 000;
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
  color: #c4c4c4;
  font-size: 16.0px;
  line-height: 1.19em;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
* {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a img {
  border: none;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
  color: #c4c4c4;
  font-size: 16.0px;
  line-height: 1.19em;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
/*input,textarea {
      -webkit-appearance:none;
      background-color:#f7f7f7;
      border:none;
      border-radius:3px;
      font-size:1em;
      font-weight:100;
    }
    */


header {
  height: 110px;
}
header .wrap {
  height: 100%;
}
header .logo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 17px;
}
header .nav ul {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
header nav ul li a {
  border-radius: px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 27px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: ##1bbeb7;
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
}
header nav ul li a.active {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #000000;
}
header nav ul li a.active:hover {
  background: #000000;
  color: #000000;
}
header nav ul li a:hover,
header nav ul li a.activeSmall {
  color: #000000;
  background: #000000;
}
```

Comment: How about showing just the relevant bits of HTML and CSS? It's ridiculous expecting people to look into hunreds of useless lines of code in order to debug a simple CSS problem.

Comment: I can see the class "nav" in the css, but no class called "nav nav-pills pull-right"

Comment: @user3479671 Those are 3 classes, not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going throw all your code since it's pretty unclear but to override those styles on basic bootstrap you just need this:

```
.nav {
  background: purple;
  color: orange;
}
.nav>li>a {
  color: orange;
}
.nav-pills>li>a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

#### [BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/e3p3tlR2Es)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few bad selectors:

```
header nav ul li a.active:hover {
```

There is no `nav` tag in your code! You do have `ul.nav` but no `nav` as its parent. So the line above should be:

```
header ul.nav li a.active:hover {
```

Make sure you do so with the others as well.

---

If the fix above doesn't work: it could be that you have some repeated rules for the nav (I see a lot of repeated rules in your code) with higher specificity, so use Dev Tools to see which rules are applied in the end, then find where they are set and modify them (or override them in your file if they are default rules) using their original specificity.

Here is a specificity calculator to help you understand which rules have higher priority than the others: http://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: I've corrected the typo..no effect.  But thank you for your comment and link.

Comment: You're welcome. Then you need to use the second part of my answer to figure out what rule is giving it the orange color and where it is set. Not sure I can help you more without seeing it live.

Comment: Did you apply those fixes I gave you?